# Draggable ondragover HTML 5

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am using ondragover event and it is working fine

```
dropZone[0].ondragover = function () {
            dropZone.addClass('hover');
            return false;
        };
```

but if user cannot drop file then how can I remove hover class from drop zone I use dragleave and dragexit event but it is not working.

```
     dropZone[0].dragleave = function () {
            dropZone.removeClass('hover');
            return false;
        };

        dropZone[0].dragexit = function () {
            dropZone.removeClass('hover');
            return false;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/KZ8bB/

jquery demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/KZ8bB/1/

do not use `dragover`, its fires every time your mouse moves on the target element use `dragenter`.

checkout: [html5rocks for drag and drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)